# UTM parameter capture from Google Ad clicks via Gravity Form not working despite successful manual testing

Tags: gravityforms, utm

Thanks in advance for your time. I'll try to do this properly.

I am driving paid clicks from Google ads to some Wordpress pages that have embedded Gravity Forms. All of my ad URLs include UTM parameters. I am doing this in order to pass those UTM parameters from the querystring as hidden fields into the form submission. My ultimate goal here is then use those UTM parameters to help sort/route the form fills and route them to the appropriate salesforce campaigns.

The challenge I'm encountering is that I am seeing zero form fills with these UTM parameters intact. I've tested the form again and again, and even sacrificed a few live paid conversions in order to test empirically. In the case of manual submissions the UTMs pull into the form just fine but it's just not happening "in the wild." I'm wracking my brain coming up with theories as to why those clicks might be qualitatively different. Are they bot clicks? Fraudulent?

Here's the test case:

| Actions Taken | Expected Behavior | Actual Behavior | Pass/Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| We apply UTM parameters to our Ad destination URLs, and have our capture form set up to grab those as hidden fields. Clicking one of our ads, you see parameters in the URL querystring. (I can see the parameterized URLs in the Google Ads list of expanded landing pages.) | Paid clicks from Google ads campaign should carry through the UTM values in the querystring to our form and capture those values as hidden fields, which we have personally verified with test submissions. | None of the paid click form fill conversion events are capturing UTM parameters. | FAIL |

Appreciate any theories, I might be too close to this (forest for the trees kinda thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically populated form fields do not work on cached pages, could this be the reason?

See docs: https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/#query-string

Comment: Thank you Phil - looking into this!

Comment: Follow-up - turns out it was indeed the parameter caching. WPEngine default settings. Blew my mind. https://wpengine.com/support/utm-gclid-variables-caching/ Spoke to them, they made a cache exclusion and gravity forms are capturing the parameters. Thanks Phil!